# Simulate mouse click AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having trouble simulating a click call to a button(displayObject) thats generated via an API call( youtube as3 API). I have not seen any mention of security reasons as to why I can not simulate a click as long as something is registered with a click handler.

Basically I checked to make sure the button made is listening to a mouse click event with:

`trace(generatedButton.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK))` which returns `true`

I proceed to than call this:

`generatedButton.dispatchEvent( new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, true) );`

And nothing happens yet if I physically click the button it works. Is there some security measure that prevents something from being fake clicked unless its origin is strictly from the system mouse?

I even set a timeout call on the click function and moved my cursor over the button and let it fire in case it was an issue of the mouse having to over the object but still nothing. I am kind of stumped at this point.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I happen to be in the exact same situation - attempting to simulate mouse clicks on Youtube-generated DisplayObjects.

I suspect you're right - that this is something security related (my simulated click on the watermark works just fine, but my "clicks" on ads are failing).

It's terribly annoying - I have an overlay that I'm trying to pass clicks "through", so that the YouTube player's ads work properly.  Otherwise, my UI code is about to get a whole lot messier.  :/

Answer (score 2):

Ok well I made a quick FLA and wrote this code and the dispatch Mouse event works perfectly..

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myClickHandler);

function myClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("clicked");
}

setTimeout(function()
{
   myButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
},2000);
```

YouTube api must block against something like this

Comment: yeah when I set this up manually in another project just to make sure I wasn't getting something wrong it worked fine. I just want to know how they could be blocking it and not a system mouse hit

Answer (score 2):

The following code works fine in my local sandbox.

```
btn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, test )

function test( e:Event ):void{
    trace('asdf');
}

btn.dispatchEvent( new MouseEvent( MouseEvent.CLICK ) );
```

So I can only come to 2 conclusions.
First is a security issue. Flash has some security issues with click events triggering the FileReference class where it can only be used if the stack has a user click in it. This issue may carry over to any artificial dispatching of that event. It works in my sandbox because the restriction doesn't apply here.


The second one is you are dispatching the event to soon and the buttons listener hasn't been added to the button from the api.

In this case try calling the dispatch  after the stage render event has been called.

```
stage.addEventListener( Event.RENDER, test )
function test( e:Event ):void{
    btn.dispatchEvent( new MouseEvent( MouseEvent.CLICK ) );
}
```

Just my guess anyway.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing a dispatchEvent, which will eventually call a method anyway, just call the method and since its expecting a MouseEvent, do `yourClickMethod(null)`

Comment: That would be fine if I created the handler function =p. The button is being generated by the youtube as3 api and I don't have access to the source of it. So whatever the handler function thats being called as a result of the click event is I have no idea. I just want to trigger that click event as if someone clicked it physically.

Comment: what happens when you actually click this button?

Comment: It plays a video in the youtube player with the youtube ID thats passed in on the create function for the button.

Looks like this ( pseudocode) :
generatedButton = youtubeVideoPlayer.createButton(video_id)

Comment: so basically the video will autoplay rather than needing the user to hit play? Surely their API has that ability, no?

Comment: Well, currently I have a video autoplay and playing the video is not a problem. The only issue is that unless a user physically clicks the play button it won't count towards view count. So if I have my own button somewhere to load and play a video it won't count towards views. Youtube gives an option to generate your own button that can load and play the video the only problem is tons of stuff would have to change in our project to switch to that. Instead I wanted to create the buttons invisibly and fake click them through clicking our existing interface. If that makes any sense =p

Comment: oops, didn't mean to add another answer :|

Answer (score 0):

You can't simulate click events on a server, it is because security issues. Instead of dispatchingEvent you can call method directly. I ll look for the description but its illegal. You can check firefox firebug logs for error description.